How can I get a lognormal fitting line in R?
I would like to plot like this figure using R:

The figure should be started from 10 in x-axis,but our data starts from 40.
Here are our data:
x_values <- c(40, 41, 42, 44, 45, 46, 48, 49, 51, 53, 54, 56, 58, 59, 61, 63, 65, 67, 69, 71, 73, 76, 78, 80, 83, 85, 88, 91, 94, 96, 99, 102, 106, 109, 112, 116, 119, 123, 127, 131, 135, 139, 143, 148, 152, 157, 162, 167, 172, 177, 183, 188, 194, 200, 206, 213, 219, 226, 233, 240, 247, 255, 263, 271, 279, 288, 297, 306, 316, 325, 335, 346, 356, 367, 379, 390, 402, 415, 428, 441, 454, 468, 483, 498, 513, 529, 545, 562, 580, 597, 616, 635, 654, 675, 696, 717, 739, 762, 785, 810)

y_values <- c(629.6425092, 693.9067558, 754.4664563, 767.5637544, 808.2602174, 794.0798188, 827.8263105, 829.0713063, 942.1401253, 941.4504438, 977.2613896, 988.3319533, 1065.3184551, 1153.8098881, 1141.3217309, 1162.6235085, 1170.0284627, 1176.2804890, 1147.8923481, 1195.5306605, 1179.2821602, 1164.1645349, 1113.1920617, 991.4336153, 1016.4254102, 954.4010424, 942.3961786, 1131.3566435, 1053.4404436, 872.8857897, 741.2625489, 669.3430698, 605.0944916, 593.7124494, 580.5191216, 565.4610143, 549.2083824, 478.9347173, 509.6879804, 328.7164120, 332.8948846, 284.6312054, 280.7722786, 335.8359343, 243.1869010, 268.7471464, 230.1890039, 200.0794310, 222.2806710, 164.0873158, 131.3721738, 112.6710788, 100.8907618, 95.8925401, 77.1103902, 67.2195979, 60.7203287, 54.2668605, 45.4695630, 40.1307280, 35.3640275, 33.1294568, 30.3855069, 25.3479543, 22.4857722, 20.4963634, 19.1942742, 16.0412082, 11.7917180, 11.3206729, 8.9647115, 8.8772804, 7.9883784, 6.5044297, 5.7742390, 4.9888767, 4.3245790, 3.8242901, 3.2763016, 2.8762140, 2.5361281, 2.2526347, 1.9660910, 1.6893935, 1.5069924, 1.3296613, 1.1608268, 1.0178425, 0.9470220, 0.8378081, 0.6925257, 0.6426677, 0.5678900, 0.5064849, 0.4364656, 0.3848985, 0.3521381, 0.3600632, 0.1613892, 0.0000000)

Opt <- data.frame(Diam = x_values, dN = y_values)


I tried plotting it using nls(), GauPro(), etc., but I hope to get modeled line through lognormal fit, and clean equation like gaussian or lognormal fit.
I tried plotting it using nls(), GauPro(), etc., but I hope to get modeled line through lognormal fit, and clean equation like gaussian or lognormal fit.
My try results red line, but i wanna get a blue line like below:

Also, I tried to make a lognormal function directly like below:
yc <- which(Opt$dN == max(Opt$dN))
yc_1 <- Opt$Diam[yc]
yc_2 <- Opt$dN[yc]/2

dNDiff <- abs(Opt$dN - yc_2)
HalfPoint <- which(dNDiff == min(dNDiff))
w1 <- Opt$Diam[HalfPoint]
FWHM = abs(w1 - yc_1)*2
realW = FWHM/sqrt(log(2))
Area = Opt$dN[yc] * 2 * (realW/2) * sqrt(pi/2)


Input <- seq(0,100, by=0.1)

FinalList = 0 + ( Area / ( realW * sqrt(pi/2) ) ) * exp( -2 * (Input - yc_1)^2 / realW^2 ) 


#plot(Opt$Diam, Opt$dN, log="x", xlim=c(10,1000))
#par(new=T)
plot(Input, FinalList)


However, it seems like weird, similar to the upper one using nls().
Could you guys help me

The graphical representation of your data in shown in figures 1 and 2 with different vertical scale :

If the model was fully Gaussian on lognormal representation the curve on figure 2 would be fully parabolic. This isn't the case. Thus your model is valid only on a partial range of the data.
The non fully correct model is the cause of the bad fitting.
If we consider only a part of the data ( in the approximative parabolic range of figure 2 ) thas is for example is taking into account only the 40 first points instead of 100. The result is shown on figures 3-4 :

All the points are drawn but the fitting calculus was made with only the 40 first points (Blue curve).
Of course this is rather arbitrary. The aim was to show the the cause of the difficulty no more.
To expect a good fitting on the whole data range a better model should be chosen. This would be a much more difficult task.
